# What's the best way to combine several answers and comments into a single answer?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

What's the best way to combine several answers and comments, all of which contribute, but none of which on its own quite answers the question, into a single answer, focused on the question?

Should I post my own "template" answer? Would it be OK to accept that answer then (provided no one found significant fault with it)?

Comment: Sounds to me like a perfect case for the community-wiki **answer**.

Comment: @Willie: How do I do that? Just answer and check the CW box?

Comment: Yes. It is as simple as that! `:-)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a perfect case for the community-wiki answer. To do that, just answer and check the CW box. It is as simple as that! :-) You can then accept the answer yourself.

Comment: +1 For posting a Community Wiki answer.